# How to test if this element is the first one with its class in the whole document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm having troubles in coming up with a conditional to load a script.

**I need a conditional that will recognize if this element is the first one in the whole document that has a certain class.**

The thing is that I've done a BBCode for a phpBB forum, and I want to put all the scripts there instead of put some in the templates, but if I do that and if the BBCode is used multiple times in the same page, the scripts mess up.

For example, this is a structure:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <div class="some-other-stuff"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div>
  <div class="youtube"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div>
  <div class="youtube"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**I want it so the script loads for the first div with the "youtube" class.** I haven't managed to try anything (yep, that clueless).

This is the script I want to use the conditional for:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".youtubebbcode_button").click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').stop(true, true).slideToggle("medium");
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but you may be looking for [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and/oor [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/). It's **well** worth your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It takes an hour, maybe two, and pays you back that time immediately.

Comment: Does this mean you are loading the same script block numerous times?

Comment: `$(".youtube:first").something()` will call `something` on the first `class="youtube"` element in the document.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. The same script is inside of every div with the "youtube" class. I want the script to load with the first one only but that it works for all of them.
:first will make the script work only for the first element with that class, which is not quite what I want.

Comment: You either need some way to keep track in your php, or use the solution I provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you are loading the same script block for each instance you could remove the click handler before adding it using `off()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".youtubebbcode_button").off('click').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.youtubevideo').stop(true, true).slideToggle("medium");
  });
 });
```

then only the last instance would activate the click handler

Comment: Wow, that works. I didn't even know that that was an alternative.

Comment: Would actually be cleaner to use a delegated event handler and then you would only include it once in your backend

Answer (score 1):

You can test if a given element is the first one in the document with a given class like this:

```
if ($(".someClass").eq(0) === element) {
    // element is the first one in the document with .someClass
}
```

Or, if you just want to apply an event handler only to the first element in the document with a given class name at a specific point in time, you can just use `.first()` or `.eq(0)` directly:

```
// apply click handler only to first element with a a class
$(".someClass").first().click(function(e) {
    // click handler only for first element
});
```

---

Or, if you your situation is dynamic (e.g. items are being added to the page all the time and you only want the click handler to act if the element is currently the first one in the page), then you can use delegated event handling:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".someClass", function(e) {
    if ($(".someClass").eq(0) === this) {
        // element clicked is the first one in the document with .someClass
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) jQuery Selector, for example:

```js
$('.test:eq(0)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
```